# breadcrumbs_on_rails with rspec controller specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, breadcrumbs

I started using breadcrumbsonrails which is working fine in production. In test my controller specs are failing and I'm wondering why.

Controller example:

```
class AdvertisementsController < ApplicationController
  layout 'mainapp'

  before_action :advertiser?
  before_action :new_add?

  add_breadcrumb 'Gallery', :gallery_index_path
  add_breadcrumb 'Post', :post_advertisements_path

  def new
    ...
    add_breadcrumb 'New', :new_post_advertisement_path
  end
```

stacktrace for rspec:

```
15:30:34 - INFO - Running: spec/controllers/advertisements_controller_spec.rb spec/routing/advertisements_routing_spec.rb
/Users/rudi/devel/w2b/app/controllers/advertisements_controller.rb:7:in `<class:AdvertisementsController>': undefined method `add_breadcrumb' for AdvertisementsController:Class (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/rudi/devel/w2b/app/controllers/advertisements_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/rudi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/rudi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/rudi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/rudi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/rudi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:360:in `require_or_load'
    from /Users/rudi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:494:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /Users/rudi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
    from /Users/rudi/devel/w2b/spec/controllers/advertisements_controller_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: Can you post your gemfile?

Comment: Or confirm that the breadcrumbs gem is available to all environments.

Comment: @RichardAE the gem is indeed available for all environments, not added to a particular group.